# how to update a list inside ng-repeat using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

i lave an ionic list

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
    Hello, {{item.name}}!
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

then, in the controller i have a event:

```
$scope.items = someData();
itemsRef.on('event', function (response) {
    console.log(response); // this is an object containing he "name" property
});
```

i would like append the `response` as a `ion-item`, without inserting html, but somehow adding the response to the items

edit:

I've tried: `$scope.items.push(response);` but weirdly enough i get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

edit: it looks like one doesn't just `$scope.items.push(response);`, but `$scope.items[next_key_here] = response;`

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/v2311770/4/)

Comment: can you add a fiddle for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried: `$scope.items.push(response);` but weirdly enough i get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

That happens because $scope.items isn't an `Array` object when you access it before it hasn't been populated with a value yet. Try doing something like this, which should work:

```
if ($scope.items && $scope.items instanceof Array) {
  $scope.items.push(response);
}
```

Comment: yes, i figure it out, see my last edit.. thanks though

Answer (score 2):

If itemRef is an Angular service, all you need is to add the object to the items array:

```
$scope.items.push( response );
```

If itemRef uses some non-Angular asynchronous service to get its response, you will need to tell Angular that things have updated:

```
$scope.$apply( function() {
    $scope.items.push( response );
});
```

If you are having problems with $scope, it's always a good idea to use a $scope variable with a dot in, for example use $scope.data.items rather than $scope.items.

See http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html for a great discussion on why.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a possible solution if you are having scope inheritance issues.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for this for a while.